# Facebook SDk 3.0 and when i have muliple app with same facebook app id, after login the app using facebook it open the randomly any app i Objetcive c

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am using the below code.

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI emailRequired:(BOOL)email {
    NSArray *permissions;
    if (email) {
        permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"publish_stream",
                       @"read_stream",
                       @"user_photos",
                       @"user_videos",
                       @"user_status",
                       @"offline_access",
                       @"publish_checkins",
                       @"manage_pages",
                       @"read_insights",
                       @"user_likes",
                       @"user_birthday",
                       @"user_website",
                       @"email",
                       nil];
    }
    else {
        permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"publish_stream",
                       @"read_stream",
                       @"user_photos",
                       @"user_videos",
                       @"user_status",
                       @"offline_access",
                       @"publish_checkins",
                       @"manage_pages",
                       @"read_insights",
                       @"user_likes",
                       @"user_birthday",
                       @"user_website",
                       nil];
    }
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:

            ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
            }];    

}
```

Comment: Please clear ur question what do u mean any app.

Comment: If i have multiple app(AppA , AppB, AppC) using the same facebook app id, If i have logged in AppA and if I tried to login using the AppC than after login it open the AppA rather than AppC.